# Detecting the mode inside a function called from a plain :map

Tags: vim

Is it possible to `:map` to a function that can detect the mode it was
called in? This is what I have:

```
func! s:ShowModeFunction()
    echomsg mode(1)
endfunc

noremap <expr> <Plug>ShowMode <SID>ShowModeFunction()

map \m <Plug>ShowMode
```

The map `\m` eventually calls the top function, which echos a string
indicating normal mode, operator-pending mode, or any of the Visual
modes.

This only works with `<expr>` on the middle map though; any colon
command would render the final `mode()` call useless, because it would
then always return "normal mode". Unfortunately, `<expr>` strictly
requires an expression on the right-hand side, and since the function
doesn't return anything, the implicit return value `0` is used, which
moves the cursor to the first column.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Just make the function return nothing, this is then a no-op in the expression mapping:

```
func! s:ShowModeFunction()
    echomsg mode(1)
    return ''
endfunc
```

If there's any other limitation in map-expr, just set a variable in there, and do the real work (including evaluating the variable) in a "normal" mapping or `:call` that you can append to your `<Plug>ShowMode` mapping (or another intermediate one, to keep the customizability).

Comment: This doesn't work for me, I now get a prompt with the mode letter, eg. 'v'. As for your second suggestion – the `:call` command is out of the question since it will make `mode()` always return `n` for "normal mode".

Comment: Your exact example works for me. Due to the `:echomsg`, the display is a little messed up, but this is not a prompt, any command (like `l` or `i`) will be immediately executed. Try replacing it with `:let g:mode = mode(1)`, that's closer to the actual use, anyway.

Comment: Fair enough, thanks. I'll leave the question open for a little while.